# can't connect with pgadmin to postgres and docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, authentication, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I have been reading several possible solutions on StackOverflow but none of them solve my problem.
Last week everything was working correctly and this week it stopped working. I don't know if it was because of the new versions of pgAdmin/Postgres having it as latest and every time it launched the containers once the previous images were deleted until everything was working and I have selected previous versions and it still doesn't work.
It does not connect to the Postgres administrator using the user admin@admin.com defined by default, I do not even see a loggin error in the traces.
I'm new to Docker + Docker-compose issues and I've followed all the examples but it hasn't worked for me again. I have deleted all the images and recreated everything from 0 and it still doesn't work. I have not changed much about the docker-compose script, I have only quoted the ports, the environment variables, I have changed the format of - VARIABLE= --> VARIABLE: but it has had no effect.

Another thing I see is that it does not create the DB with the script that is passed.
Any ideas?
I leave here the complete docker-compose script and the database creation script.

When I set into pgAdmin login: admin@admin.com/qwerty don't enter

NOTE: Postgres DB is started

Thank you

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  # Other services

  ############################################################################
  ## Database configuration
  ##
  ############################################################################
  postgres_db:
    networks:
      - payment_network
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15.6
    ports:
      - "3432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./dbfiles:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - /var/lib/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgressql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres

  pgadmin4:
    networks:
      - payment_network
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:8.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=qwerty
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db

networks:
  payment_network:
    name: payment_network
    driver: bridge
```

Script to init DB

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE USER springboot WITH PASSWORD 'qwerty';
        CREATE DATABASE  springboot;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE springboot TO springboot;
EOSQL
```

Comment: On two lines of `volumes:`, try to add at the end of them `:rw`, like `./dbfiles:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:rw`

Comment: @J-JacquesM It doesn't work, it doesn't create the DB. Still not logging in to pgAdmin

Comment: The script don't execute. What happen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened but I changed the username and password and it allowed me to log in.